# PHP shell_exec grep not getting all running scripts through cronjob

Tags: php, cron, grep

I just got in a trouble, i were trying to make cronjob to run every 5 minutes, and within php i tried to check if my script is already running, if yes: exit, otherwise continue with running.
Everything went good until i let cron job to run script, and then it started to run at every 5 minutes (*every time it runned, and i got few scripts running in background instead of planned only 1), but when i try to run the script from browser it returns good and recognize all running scripts.. I tried to log results and got that **script runned from cronjob** using following code:

```
$php_search = "connect.php";
$result = shell_exec("ps aux | grep -v grep |  grep ".$php_search ); 
/* checking result & code for listening connection -- forever running */
```

gets only as result the current running cronjob (not the other that is already running in background). For example if the cron job runned this script for 5 times, even the 6th run would return as result just itself nothing else from running scripts?

```
Result:
.....    1  0.0  0.0  20164   244 ?        S    09:40   0:00 jailshell (.....) [init] ell -c /usr/bin/php /home/...../public_html/...../connect.php
.....    2  0.0  0.0 361412 15444 ?        S    09:40   0:00 /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php-cgi /home/...../public_html/...../connect.php
```

Am i doing something wrong with `grep` or there is some limitation within cronjob as it works when i run the script through browser?

I am using dedicated server, so if there's some option i could change i can do it...

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running the scripts with the same user of your http service?

Comment: Yes, the user is same, the cronjob and executed from browser shows same user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it working, and it was option on root account (whm) following menu:

```
Account Functions -> Manage Shell Access
```

There i have just turned shell access for account from ***Disabled Shell*** to ***Normal Shell***

And now it works and `grep` get's all other running scripts..